# Passing value of input tag to a search button tag - ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, containers, styled-components

Any input on how I can fix this...

My goal here is for the user to search 'Jane Smith' into the search bar, click the search button and display the cards that contain 'Jane Smith'

Currently with what I have, the user searches for 'Jane Smith' which is saved as the 'term' and once the user clicks the search button the 'fetchStudents' function fails saying it doesn't have 'term'

I'm having trouble passing a value of 'term' from SearchBarInput tag over to the SearchBarButton tag, so in the student container I can use it in the mapDispatchToProps function.

> My searchBar component consists of

```
const SearchBar = ({ onClick, value }) => (
    <SearchBarWrapper>
        <div>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="search" className="searchIcon" />
            <SearchBarInput
                name="searchBarInput"
                placeholder=" Search for something..."
                label="searchBar"
                defaultValue={value}
            />
            <SearchBarButton onClick={onClick}>Search</SearchBarButton>
        </div>
    </SearchBarWrapper>
    );

    export default SearchBar;
```

> In my student container I have

```
const Students = ({ studentsPayload = [], onClick }) => (
    <StudentsContainer>
        <SearchBarContainer>
            <SearchBar onClick={onClick} />
        </SearchBarContainer>
        {studentsPayload.length > 0 ? (
            <StudentsCard data={studentsPayload} />
        ) : null}
    </StudentsContainer>
);



const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({ onClick: ({ target: { value } }) => dispatch(fetchStudents(value)) });


const mapStateToProps = ({ students: { studentsPayload } }) => ({ studentsPayload });
/**
 * Connects component to redux store
 */
const enhancer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
)(StudentSearch);

export default enhancer;
```

> My fetchStudents in actions looks like this

```
export const fetchStudents = term => async dispatch => {
        try {
            const { data: { items } } = await fetchData(
            `${process.env.REACT_APP_STUDENTS_URLP1}${term}${process.env.REACT_APP_STUDENTS_URLP2}`);
            dispatch({ type: FETCH_STUDENTS, studentsPayload: items });
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(error);
        }
    };
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ```<SearchBarButton onClick={(e) => onClick(value)}>Search</SearchBarButton>```

Can you try above code, as you haven't passed the input value to click function and you're using the event of button component which deosn't have the input value access.

Comment: I tried that, and it throws an error in the mapDispatchToProps function saying "cannot read property 'target' of undefined"  and also in the SearchBar function it says 'e' is not being used.

Comment: I want to do something like <SearchBarButton onClick={onClick} valueToPass={SearchBarInput.defaultValue}>Search</SearchBarButton> .  This doesnt work, but im wondering is there a way to pass the defualtValue from 'SearchBarInput' to the 'SearchBarButton'...

Comment: const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({ onClick: (value) => dispatch(fetchStudents(value)) });
 This is how mapDispatchToProps should look like as you're passing value and event object

Comment: That fixed the error, but the 'value' passed inside onClick is empty. whats in SearchBarInput is not being sent over to SearchBarButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help! I solved the problem by making the following changes :)

> In the Search bar component

```
const SearchBar = ({ onClickButton, value, onValueChange }) => (
    <SearchBarWrapper>
        <div>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="search" className="searchIcon" />
            <SearchBarInput
                name="searchBarInput"
                label="searchBar"
                placeholder="Search for something"
                value={value}
                onChange={onValueChange} 
            />
            <SearchBarButton onClick={() => onClickButton(value)}>Search</SearchBarButton>
        </div>
    </SearchBarWrapper>
);

export default SearchBar;
```

> In the Student container

```
const Students = ({ studentsPayload = [], onClickButton }) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    const handleChange = ({ target: { value } }) => setValue(value);
    return (
        <StudentsContainer>
            <SearchBarContainer>
                <SearchBar
                    onClickButton={onClickButton}
                    onValueChange={handleChange}
                    value={value}
                />
            </SearchBarContainer>
            {studentsPayload.length > 0 ? (
                <StudentsCard data={studentsPayload} />
            ) : null}
        </StudentsContainer>
    );
};


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({ onClickButton: value => dispatch(fetchStudents(value)) });

const mapStateToProps = ({ students: { studentsPayload } }) => ({ studentsPayload });
/**
 * Connects component to redux store
 */
const enhancer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
)(Students);

export default enhancer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the `SearchBar` component to utilize the `useState` hook. Then you can pass an `onChange` handler to your `SearchInput` that takes in the event and updates the `SearchBar` state based off of the `event.target.value`. Then when you hit submit, you can pass in the input value that you have stored in state.